# i2c does not detect the address

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded, i2c

I am using Raspberry Pi, so I have install:

```sh
sudo apt-get -y python-smbus
sudo apt-get -y i2c-tools
```

also I have enable I²C from the interface.

When I type this command: `i2cdetect -y 1 ...` it does not see the address. I will post a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyIxE.png) of it.

I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get -y i2c-tools , detect the slaves electrically wired on the I2C bus of the Raspberry , if it does not detect them and check this wiring and these standards (pull up resistance) and that a slave is well configured at the other end

attention according to the version of raspberry the port can be 0 or 1